# Why do PDFs open in large windows or at high screen resolution?

Tags: tcpdf

I utilize tcpdf to generate PDFs which works great.  Once in a while a user will ask why they open in large windows or at a high screen resolution, like 150%.  This causes them to have to resize the pdf for easier viewing every time they open one.  Am I correct in thinking this is a client setting OR is there some way I can configure/adjust the pdf generated by tcpdf to open in a specific window size and magnification?